# Possible Bug in LinearSolveFunction with Sparse Vectors

Tags: functions, bugs, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 5.0 and fixed in 11.0** 
`LinearSolveFunction` is new in 5.0

---

Consider the following set of equations and corresponding variables:

```
eqns1 ={2 x == 2 - 4 y, 3 y == 4 z, 2 z + 4 t == 3, 3 t + 2 z == 5};
vars = {x, y, z, t};
```

We can use `CoefficientArrays` to get the array of coefficient of the variables, and use that to solve the set of equations:

```
{v1, m1} = CoefficientArrays[eqns1, vars];
LinearSolve[m1][-v1] (* This creates a LinearSolveFunction then applies it to -v1 *)
```

$ \{-\frac{41}{3}, \frac{22}{3}, \frac{11}{2}, -2\} $

Now we make the set of equations symbolic and repeat the process:

```
eqns2 = {b x == 2 - c y, a y == c z, b z + c t == 3, a t + b z == 5};
{v2, m2} = CoefficientArrays[eqns2, vars];
```

Now we solve the equations:

```
LinearSolve[m2][-v2]
```

And *Mathematica* just crashes as if you typed `Quit[]`.

Note that `LinearSolveFunction` is the culprit because you can still get the answer without crashing *Mathematica* by just using regular `LinearSolve` (without first creating a `LinearSolveFunction`) as follows:

```
LinearSolve[m2, -v2]
```

$\{\frac{2 a^2 b - 2 a b c - 3 a c^2 + 5 c^3}{a b^2 (a - c)}, \frac{
 3 a c - 5 c^2}{a b (a - c)}, \frac{3 a - 5 c}{b (a - c)}, \frac{2}{a - c}\}$

Also, note that if we pass the vector as a `List`, it also works fine

```
ls = LinearSolve[m2]; (* create a LinearSolveFunction *)
ls[{2, 0, 3, 5}] // ExpandAll // Together
```

Can anyone reproduce this? I get the same behavior on both *Mathematica* **10.3.1** and **10.4**. OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: I can reproduce the crash on 10.4. A workaround is to apply `Normal[]` to `v2`. The simpler `LinearSolve[m2][SparseArray[1 -> 1, 4]]` also crashes, so I'm inclined to think that the `LinearSolveFunction[]` chokes on sparse vectors for some reason.

Comment: @J.M., yeah I know `Normal` works which is why I stated that just using a normal `List` doesn't crash *Mathematica*. About Sparse vectors, that was my initial title, maybe I should include that back.

Comment: Also reproduces in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1, win10 64bit.

Comment: Just checked in 5.2; `LinearSolveFunction[]` chokes on sparse vectors in that version as well. Clearly an old problem. Even the (now deprecated and undocumented) function `LUBackSubstitution[]` chokes if given a sparse vector.

Comment: Bug report filed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in the just released [Mathematica 11.0](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-11/):

```
eqns2 = {b x == 2 - c y, a y == c z, b z + c t == 3, a t + b z == 5};
vars = {x, y, z, t};
{v2, m2} = CoefficientArrays[eqns2, vars];
LinearSolve[m2][-v2]

(* {(2 - (c^2 (3 - (2 c)/(a - c)))/(a b))/b, (c (3 - (2 c)/(a - c)))/(a b),
    (3 - (2 c)/(a - c))/b, 2/(a - c)} *)
```